# Angular rxjs memory leak

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

If I have a component and I want to unsubscribe using takeuntil, will switching from the below Before to After cause a memory leak (when using many subjects)

**Before**

```
class OnInit, OnDestroy{
private subjectA: Subject<TypeA> = new Subject();

public subjectA$: Observable<TypeA> = this.subjectA.asObservable();

ngOnDestroy {
    this.subjectA.complete();
}
}
```

**After**

```
   class OnInit, OnDestroy{
    private subjectA: Subject<TypeA> = new Subject();
    private destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
    
    public subjectA$: Observable<TypeA> = this.subjectA.asObservable.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$));
    
    onDestroy {
         this.destroy$.next(true);
         this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
    }
    }
```

The reason I ask is that the private subject never really is destroyed -- it just stops taking from it.

Comment: Where are you subscribing to it? If you're using the async pipe there's no need to unsubscribe manually

Comment: Its used in a service that wont allow async piping at the moment

Comment: In 99% of the cases you shouldn't subscribe from a service so I'd say start digging here or share more code if possible

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in the code. It should be "ngOnDestroy", not "onDestroy".

```
 Component implements OnDestroy {

  ngOnDestroy() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Also you may be interested to use `ReplaySubject` instead of `Subject` for `destroy$` (in 99% cases it's not necessary, but in 1% of cases it could prevent "hard-to-catch" memory leaks).

Comment: Just fixed. Looking into ReplaySubject now will research now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above,

This syntax isnt correct.

`public subjectA$: Observable<TypeA> = this.subjectA.asObservable(takeuntil(this.destroy$));`

you should change this to

`public subjectA$: Observable<TypeA> = this.subjectA.asObservable().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$));`